# Making an attic space into walkin closet

Tags: floor, framing

I have an attic space which is on top of my living room and 13'X20' size. I am trying to convert this space into a walk in closet. It has 14, 2x4’s joists spacing 16” on center on 13’ direction. It has purlin on 20’ direction and has 2 braces diagonally attached to the Purlin probably to support the Rafters.  To make this area strong I am thinking about adding more 2x4’s or 2x6’s in between the existing 2X4’s ones. I also want to remove the Purlin by adding knee wall to support the roof. Will it be a good suggestions to do this?  And then put ¾” plywood and on top laminate floor. Or is there any new way you can suggest me to remove the bracing and have clear usable space. Please provide me suggestions. 
[image]

Comment: I'm definitely not up on my structural code, but for the little reading I have done, I know 2x4's are not going to cut it and 2x6's may be pushing it depending on how much weight you plan to store up there (clothes may be fine, but if it one day turns into a storage area for boxes as I would guess to be likely for you or a future owner). Generally 2x8's are the minimum I recall seeing to carry any appreciable load.

Comment: 2x6 are never adequate for joists in anything larger than a stair landing (4' x 4' max). You'd need 2x10 or engineered joists to span 13'. Less may work, but it'll be bouncy and could result in sagging where you don't want sagging.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is very helpful.  Also what you guys suggest me about removing the Purlin with an knee wall.. Or something else?